# How to make sure all slave threads are waited for conditional variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost-thread

I am running the following chunk of the code. This code is going to create 5 slave threads and 1 main thread. All slave threads are waited for the main thread to make the data ready and when the data gets ready, all slaves will notify to start processing.

My question is, it is possible that before the slave threads start waiting for the `conditional_variable`, the main thread make the data ready and notify the waited threads. In this case, some threads which were waited will get the notification and start processing but the ones which were not waited, will starting waiting for a notification which will NEVER come.

If you run this example, this case won't happen but I am looking for a way to make sure that all the slave threads are waiting for the notification, then notifying them. Do you know how can I do that?

```
/*
  Condition Variables - Many waiting threads

  Shows how one condition variable can be used to notify multiple threads
  that a condition has occured.

  * Part of "Threading with Boost - Part IV: Condition Variables", published at:

      http://antonym.org/boost

  Copyright (c) 2015 Gavin Baker <gavinb@antonym.org>
  Published under the MIT license, see LICENSE for details
*/

#include <cstdio>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::condition_variable data_ready_cond;
boost::mutex data_ready_mutex;
bool data_ready = false;

void master_thread()
{
    printf("+++ master thread\n");

    // Pretend to work
    printf("    master sleeping...\n");
    boost::chrono::milliseconds sleepDuration(750);
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(sleepDuration);

    // Let other threads know we're done
    printf("    master notifying...\n");
    data_ready = true;
    data_ready_cond.notify_all();

    printf("--- master thread\n");
}

void slave_thread(int id)
{
    printf("+++ slave thread: %d\n", id);

    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock(data_ready_mutex);
    while (!data_ready)
    {
        data_ready_cond.wait(lock);
    }

    printf("--- slave thread: %d\n", id);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Spawning threads...\n");

    boost::thread slave_1(slave_thread, 1);
    boost::thread slave_2(slave_thread, 2);
    boost::thread slave_3(slave_thread, 3);
    boost::thread slave_4(slave_thread, 4);

    boost::thread master(master_thread);

    printf("Waiting for threads to complete...\n");

    slave_1.join();
    slave_2.join();
    slave_3.join();
    slave_4.join();
    master.join();

    printf("Done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when debuggin code put some code to randomly sleep inside threads, most times I catch some bug this way. do you want some thread don't see the notification then make it sleep before it happens and see itìf there's some condition forcin others to wait it

Comment: Your condition predicate is `data_ready`, and you're modifying it in `master_thread` without the mutex, whos sole purpose is to protect it, *latched*. That in itself is wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig OK! I will add the mutex but it is not a fix to my problem. I am looking for a mechanism to make sure all the slave threads are waited already.

Comment: @mmostajab this is the fix for your problem

Comment: @Slava Is there any way to see if the thread is waited or not?

Comment: @mmostajab you do not need that, if you put mutex lock in main thread before you change flag code will work as it is

Comment: @mmostajab You started the slave threads. Whether they've each in-turn latched, checked, and entered-wait (thus unlatching) isn't particularly relevant so long as the predicate data is properly protected (which it currently is *not* in master). If you really want to ensure all slaves are sitting on the wait it is possible with a little more work, but frankly it is also fairly pointless.

Comment: @WhozCraig Your point fixes my problem but I like to make sure all slaves are on the wait, can you please help me how can I do that?

Comment: "I like to make sure all slaves are on the wait" - *why* ? If the predicate data is properly managed it won't matter whether they're sitting on a cvar wait or not (which is somewhat the point of proper predicate management).

Comment: @mmostajab I do not quite understand why you need to make sure all slave threads are waiting, but you can simply put a counter and increase it before you enter `wait()` and decrease it afterwards, and check that counter under the same mutex lock in main thread.

Comment: @Slava Assume the `data_ready=false`, an slave checks the value of `data_ready`, as it is false it will go for waiting for the `notification` but before the `wait` functions executes, the slave thread gets suspended and the master thread makes the `data_ready=true` and then notify the waited threads. In this case, the waited threads are going to be notified but the thread which was suspended after `data_ready==true` and before wait will wait forever.

Even if I use a counter before, `wait` it cannot eliminate this problem.

Comment: @Slava but I think this will happen very very very rare :)

Comment: @mmostajab it will not happen at all, wait() suspends execution and unlocks mutex atomically. I think you are missing this point. So if slave will be suspended before wait() mutex will remain locked.

Comment: @mmostajab counter will not eliminate the problem, it is an answer how to count how many slave threads are waiting, for whatever reason you need it. If you still think you need to make sure all slaves are waiting to eliminate the problem discussed, you are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have race condition - setting flag and notifying slave threads is not atomic. So you just have to lock `data_ready_mutex` before you are modifying `data_ready` flag in main thread. This will eliminate race condition, slave thread either will see `data_ready` false and go to wait on condition variable and will be notified, or it will acquire mutex lock only after `data_ready` is set to `true` and so it will not wait at all.

Comment: This is as accurate as I could/would have written it. The fundamental rule for cvars+mutexes is simple: *Never change, **nor even check**, the predicate data state unless the predicate mutex is locked.* The master thread is violating that fundamental rule. Upticked.